# I'm coding in Python and keep receiving: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2019' in position 31: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, error-handling, ascii

The code below is the timeclienthandler.py code that I created in Visual Studio Code. It works sometimes but it still gives me the error if I continuously run the code. I don't understand how it works off and on.

```
from time import ctime
from threading import Thread
import random


class TimeClientHandler(Thread):


    def __init__(self, client):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.client = client


    def run(self):
        msgList = ["There are some idiots who always answer 'No' to every question, now tell me. Are you one of them?","There's nothing to fear. Except maybe that weird guy over there.","If I'm driving you crazy just remember to put on your seat belt.","I wondered why the baseball was getting bigger. Then it hit me.","You're Just Jealous Because The Voices Are Talking To Me.","Quickest way to get on your feet...miss a car payment.","Why do psychics ask your name?","I'm not opinionated. I'm just always right.","Sanity is the playground for the unimaginative.","It isn't homework unless it's due tomorrow."]
        msg = msgList[random.randint(0,len(msgList))]
        msge ="\n"+msg
        self.client.send(bytes(ctime() + msge,"ascii"))
        self.client.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you specified is occuring at line 18 in your code

Specifically -  bytes(ctime() + msge,"ascii")

This error occured because of encoding you specified "ascii" which only supports the following characters:

['\x00', '\x01', '\x02', '\x03', '\x04', '\x05', '\x06', '\x07', '\x08', '\t', '\n', '\x0b', '\x0c', '\r', '\x0e', '\x0f', '\x10', '\x11', '\x12', '\x13', '\x14', '\x15', '\x16', '\x17', '\x18', '\x19', '\x1a', '\x1b', '\x1c', '\x1d', '\x1e', '\x1f', ' ', '!', '"', '#', '$', '%', '&', "'", '(', ')', '*', '+', ',', '-', '.', '/', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', ':', ';', '<', '=', '>', '?', '@', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '[', '\', ']', '^', '_', '`', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '{', '|', '}', '~', '\x7f']

but the input you are giving to it is '\u2019' or {’}, which is not in the above list hence resulting in the UnicodeEncodeError ('ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2019' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128))

So the solution to this problem is to change the specified encoding (ascii) to (UTF-8)
Try the code below:

```
from time import ctime
from threading import Thread
import random


class TimeClientHandler(Thread):


def __init__(self, client):
    Thread.__init__(self)
    self.client = client


def run(self):
    msgList = ["There are some idiots who always answer 'No' to every question, now tell me. Are you one of them?","There's nothing to fear. Except maybe that weird guy over there.","If I'm driving you crazy just remember to put on your seat belt.","I wondered why the baseball was getting bigger. Then it hit me.","You're Just Jealous Because The Voices Are Talking To Me.","Quickest way to get on your feet...miss a car payment.","Why do psychics ask your name?","I'm not opinionated. I'm just always right.","Sanity is the playground for the unimaginative.","It isn't homework unless it's due tomorrow."]
    msg = msgList[random.randint(0,len(msgList))]
    msge ="\n"+msg
    self.client.send(bytes(ctime() + msge,"UTF-8"))
    self.client.close()
```

Comment: You can also try other encodings as well like : UTF-16 , UTF-32 , GB18030 etc...                                    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding

Answer (score 0):

Encoding with **UTF-8**.

Turn to the folder `Lib\site-packages` in **current used python interpreter**, create a file called `sitecustomize.py` and add the following code in it:

```
#coding=utf8 
import sys 
reload(sys) 
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```

Then restart the VS Code to see if the question goes away.